# Basis of a Finite Dimensional Algebra with a Finitely Generated Relation Set By Computer

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, computer-algebra

Let $A$ be a noncommutative finitely generated algebra with a finitely generated set of relations. Moreover, assume that $A$ is finite dimensional as a vector space.

What I want to know is, can Mathematica (or any other package) be used to find the dimension of $A$ given only the generators of $A$ and the generators of the set of relations? Or, even better, can Mathematica (or any other package) be used to find a basis of $A$ given only the generators of $A$ and the generators of the set of relations?

Basic examples would be particularily helpful.

Comment: I use GAP (http://www.gap-system.org/) and the non-commutative Gröbner basis package gbnp (http://mathdox.org/products/gbnp/). You will find examples in the manual.

Comment: I used to use Steve Linton's Vector Enumeration but this is now deprecated.

Comment: Not really related, but still: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85400/symbolic-computations-with-differential-operators-universal-envelopings-i-e-non

Comment: If you know A to be a basic algebra then this can be done in Magma.   http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/898  Magma may also be able to do more general types of algebra, have a look at the Algebras section of the handbook.  There is an online calculator if you don't have institutional access to Magma but it is limited to computations taking at most a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was mentioned in my comment, you can use [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) and the noncommutative Gröbner bases package [gbnp](http://mathdox.org/products/gbnp/), written by Arjeh M. Cohen and Jan Willem Knopper.

Here you have an **example**:

Assume that you want to compute the dimension and a basis for the algebra $A$ with generators $a,b,c$ and relations 
$a^2 =b^2=c^2=0$, 
$ab + ca + bc = 0$ and $ba + cb + ac = 0$.

(This algebra is related to Schubert calculus and it was first 
discovered by Fomin and Kirillov, see [MR1667680 (2001a:05152)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1667680).)

```
gap> LoadPackage("gbnp");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading  GBNP 0.9.5 (Non-commutative Gröbner bases)
by A.M. Cohen (http://www.win.tue.nl/~amc) and
   D.A.H. Gijsbers (D.A.H.Gijsbers@tue.nl).
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
true
gap> A := FreeAssociativeAlgebraWithOne(Rationals, "a", "b", "c");;
gap> a := A.a;;
gap> b := A.b;;
gap> c := A.c;;
gap> rels := [a^2, b^2, c^2, a*b+c*a+b*c, b*a+c*b+a*c];;
gap> K := GP2NPList(rels);;                             
gap> G := SGrobner(K);;
gap> Display(DimQA(G,3));
12
gap> PrintNPList(BaseQA(G, 3, 0));
 1 
 a 
 b 
 c 
 ab 
 ac 
 ba 
 bc 
 aba 
 abc 
 bac 
 abac
```

Here is the complete reference related to this algebra:

Fomin, Sergey; Kirillov, Anatol N. Quadratic algebras, Dunkl elements, and Schubert calculus. Advances in geometry, 147--182, Progr. Math., 172, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1999. [MR1667680 (2001a:05152)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1667680).)

Comment: Great. That looks like just what I want! But I'm having installing the package. On the package page it says:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
unpack GBNP-1.0.1.tar.gz in the pkg subdirectory of your GAP installation (or in the pkg subdirectory of any other GAP root directory, for example one added with the -l argument) with the following command:

 tar -xvzf GBNP-1.0.1.tar.gz.
%%%%%%%%%%%%

I typed this into GAP and got an error. What/Where is the pkg subdirectory?



Comment: Where have you installed GAP? Usually the GAP package directory is gap4r4/pkg/.

Comment: @Leandro, do you know if there is a way to do this sort of thing in GAP when the algebra is defined over a field of rational functions?

Comment: @MTS, Maybe not, but I am not sure. What about Magma?