# Noncommutative computational package

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings, mathematical-software

I am wondering if there is a program which can do simple operations over noncommutative rings, like expand products and substitute one expression for another.

To clarify, consider the following situation.  I have two reductions $ab\mapsto 1$ and $ca\mapsto c-1$.  If I consider the monomial $cab$ I can reduce it in two ways: $cab=c(ab)=c$ or $cab=(ca)b=(c-1)b=cb-b$.  I can combine these computations to arrive at a third reduction $cb\mapsto b+c$.

I'm in a situation where I have upwards of twelve reduction rules, and it gets very complicated doing the reductions.  I find myself making small errors.  Thus, the need for a machine to do these computations for me.

To make this more precise, is there a program where I can first input a number of reductions, and then second have it work on a monomial and spit out a reduced form?

Comment: Partly related MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85400/symbolic-computations-with-differential-operators-universal-envelopings-i-e-non  Symbolic computations with differential operators (universal envelopings i.e. non-commutative variables) ?

Answer (score 6):

You may be satisfied by some noncommutative Gröbner basis programs: I know of the standalone [Bergman](http://servus.math.su.se/bergman/) and the GAP package [GBNP](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/gbnp.html).

Comment: +1. "Bergman" is a very helpful program.

Answer (score 3):

There is this non-commutative algebra package for Mathematica that is quite extensive

- http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/

It can handle the symbolic computations in the question, among many other things.

Answer (score 2):

[Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) can certainly deal with that. Not sure about other packages; [Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) has been approaching a non-commutative extension for years, but I'm not sure of its status.

Comment: The singular nc extension is called Plural (of course); it deals only with special classes of noncommutative algebras called G-algebras http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/latest/sing_445.htm#SEC485

Answer (score 1):

You can do quick computations with http://servus.math.su.se/bergman/demo.html

(The page deals with homogeneous relations, but you can add a new variable $t$, homogenise the relations you want using it, and the add relations saying that $t$ commutes with $a$, $b$ and $c$. Doing this with your relations gives what seems to be infinitely many elements in the (lexicographic) Groebner basis)

Answer (score 1):

You could try SAGE.  They have an [online version](http://www.sagemath.org/) (free) where everything is in python and you can run programs from the cloud.  The downloadable version has a bit more functionality but is harder to use.