# Software for noncommutative Groebner bases over rational function fields

Tags: computer-algebra, mathematical-software, associative-algebras

I am wondering whether there is any software package that can compute Groebner bases for noncommutative algebras defined over the field of rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(q)$.

I have tried the GAP package [GBNP](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/gbnp.html) but I can't seem to even construct $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ in it, much less define an algebra over it.

I have also tried the Mathematica package [NCGB](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) released by UC San Diego, but it suggests that I specialize to a rational value of $q$, which is not what I want to do.

Free software is preferred, but I am also interested in finding out if there is proprietary software that can do the job. Does Magma do this?

Comment: Have you tried searching the magma manual for Groebner bases: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/groebner_bases

Comment: @NeilHoffman, that seems to be for commutative rings. I did find this: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/900#9876 which indicates that Magma can do Groebner basis calculations for noncommutative algebras, but it doesn't say much about what coefficient fields are possible.

Comment: perhaps Singular can do it? You might want to check it out: http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Magma is fairly general in base rings. Following their example:

```
> Q<q> := FunctionField(Rationals());
> F<x,y,z> := FreeAlgebra(Q,3);
> B := [x^2-q*y*z,q^2*x*y-y*z,y*x*q-z^2,q*y^3-x*z];
> I := ideal<F | B>;
> GroebnerBasis(I);
```

I am not sure exactly what functionality you want, but if it can handle the basis operations, then Groebner should be possible (though may be slow).

Comment: Previous question on this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108095/noncommutative-computational-package

Comment: I've seen that other question, but it didn't address the question of which base fields are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

FriCAS (fricas.sf.net) can compute Groebner bases
for noncommutative polynomial rings of solvable
type defined over large class of base rings.
Currently FriCAS provides Ore algebras, but
Groebner basis code can accept user domains
as long as they stick to provided interface.

Defining general Ore algebras is somewhat bulky,
so I gve example for differential operators:

```
Pdo := PartialDifferentialOperator(Polynomial(Integer), Symbol)
xx := D(x)$Pdo + y*D(z)$Pdo
yy := D(y)$Pdo - x*D(z)$Pdo
L := xx*xx + yy*yy
gPak := NGroebnerPackage(Polynomial(Integer),  IndexedExponents(Symbol), Symbol, Pdo)
groebner([L, xx])$gPak
```